# Matrix similarity & Characteristic polynomial (linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to practice this kind of material, so as a self practice, I though about this:
A1 and A2 are both nxn matrices.
A1 is Invertible matrix. A1A2 & A2A1 are necessarily similar? and how about PA1A2 and PA2A1? (=their characteristic polynomial).

I think they don't necessarily need to be similiar, just by logic, but I really don't know to explain it, especially in a mathematics and algebraic way. I would be happy if one could explain it to me. It would make my understanding better.

Thanks.

Comment: Observe that $A_1A_2 = A_1(A_2A_1)A_1^{-1}$

Comment: Don't get it yet, sorry...

Comment: The answer to your question is: Yes, the matrices $A_1A_2$ and $A_2A_1$ are similar provided that $A_1$ is invertible. Indeed, conjugation by $A_1$ transforms $A_2A_1$ into $A_1A_2$.

Comment: @ivanpenev - sir, i'm afriad that I still don't understnad... Can you extend your explain please? and what about their  characteristic polynomial?

Comment: I'm sorry, unless you tell me more specifically what you don't understand, I don't know how make my explanation clearer. Regarding the characteristic polynomials, we have $$\det(TAT^{-1}-\lambda) = \det(T(A-\lambda)T^{-1}) = \det(T)\det(A-\lambda)\det(T)^{-1} = \det(A-\lambda)$$ for any $n\times n$ matrix $A$ and any invertible $n\times n$ matrix $T$. This shows that the characteristic polynomials of similar matrices are always equal.